# Flutter: TextField will not scroll down when new lines are added

Tags: flutter, dart

Update: this problem may be because of setting the TextField's 'readOnly' attribute to true.  If so, I still need to make sure the keyboard does not pop up, since I set readOnly to true to disable the keyboard.

## BACKGROUND

My app adds letters and newlines from a custom button widgets to a display that has a TextField widget.  I do not use a keyboard for this.  I use the Provider package and a ChangeNotifier called AppBrain to manage state.  AppBrain has the text information and edits it when a letter is selected from the selection bar.

The textfield is a scrollable widget when there are too many lines to fit in its dimensions. But whenever I add letters and a new line of text is created, the textfield does not scroll down and the cursor and edited line is obscured.

I would like to know an easy way to scroll until the cursor is visible again.  (When the cursor is at the end of the text, I can scroll to the bottom.  When it is in the middle of the text, I just need to scroll it one line down.)

## POSSIBLE FIXES

1. When I reenable the keyboard to edit the TextField, it does it automatically.  If anyone knows how the keyboard edits the TextField, I might be able to add that to my addWord function.
2. I tried using a ScrollController to scroll the TextField using its animateTo() function.  The problem I have is that I usually need to just scroll down 1 line, but I don't have the exact pixel height of my lines of text.  I also don't know when a line wraps to a new line, which would require a scroll down.
3. Perhaps if I had the position of my cursor, I could use it along with my TextField's dimensions to scroll down accordingly.

[Picture of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aemI3.png)

## CODE

**Textfield widget in Text Display**

Portion of code in Text Display

```
...
Positioned(//Text Display
  top:0,
  left:0,
  width:kScreenDim.dx,
  height:290,
  child: Container(
    color: kAppBarBackgroundColor,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: kTextMargin),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft:Radius.elliptical(17,20),
          topRight: Radius.elliptical(17,20)
        ),
        color:kTextDisplayColor
      ),
      child: Consumer<AppBrain>( 
        builder: (context,appBrain, child)=> TextField(//       <<=====
          controller: appBrain.textDisplayController,
          scrollController: appBrain.textDisplayScrollController,
          
          readOnly: true,
          autofocus: true,
          showCursor: true,
          maxLines: null,
          decoration: null,
          cursorColor: Colors.red,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: kTextFontSize,)
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```

**Enter Button**

Example of a button that adds a letter to the TextField

```
BottomButton(//ENTER BUTTON
  onPressed: () {
    var appBrain = Provider.of<AppBrain>(context, listen:false);//   <<===
    appBrain.addWord('\n');
  },
  label: 'Enter',
  color: kEnterButtonColor,
)
```

**App Brain**

Relevant portions of AppBrain, a ChangeNotifier.  The main summary of addWord is that I directly edit textDisplayController.text and textDisplayController.selection.

```
class AppBrain with ChangeNotifier {
...
  TextEditingController textDisplayController = TextEditingController();
  ScrollController textDisplayScrollController = ScrollController();
...


...
  void addWord (String aWord){//Inserts/replaces word into text of TextDisplay

    //DIRECTLY EDITS textDisplayController.text and textDisplayController.selection

    String displayText = textDisplayController.text;  
    List<int> selectionRange = getSelectionRange();
    int cursorCharIndex = selectionRange[0]; //position in text
    //position in _numTChars
    int newCursorDisplayIndex = getCursorDisplayIndex(cursorCharIndex);
    
    //Update text and _numTChar.
    //If there is a highlighted selection of text to be replaced,
    if (selectionRange[0]!=selectionRange[1]){
      int lidx = selectionRange[0];
      int ridx = selectionRange[1];
      int lDisplayIdx = getCursorDisplayIndex(lidx);
      int rDisplayIdx = getCursorDisplayIndex(ridx);
    
      textDisplayController.text = displayText.substring(0,lidx) + aWord;   <<===
      if (ridx < displayText.length) {
        textDisplayController.text += displayText.substring(ridx);
      }
      _numTChars[lDisplayIdx] = aWord.length;
      _numTChars = _numTChars.sublist(0, lDisplayIdx+1) +
          _numTChars.sublist(rDisplayIdx);
    }else {//Insert character at the cursor
      if (displayText.length == 0 || cursorCharIndex == displayText.length) {
        textDisplayController.text += aWord;
      } else {
        textDisplayController.text = displayText.substring(0, cursorCharIndex)+
            aWord + displayText.substring(cursorCharIndex);
      }
      _numTChars.insert(newCursorDisplayIndex, aWord.length);
    }
    
    //place the cursor in the correct position.
    cursorCharIndex += aWord.length;
     //                                                             <<===
    textDisplayController.selection = TextSelection( 
        baseOffset: cursorCharIndex, 
        extentOffset: cursorCharIndex
    );
    
    notifyListeners();
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When keyboard pops up it covers bottom of you widget. you should use `MediaQuery` to get bottom padding after keyboard pops up.

wrap your page in a `Padding` widget and set the `bottom` like this.

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
    ),
    child: YourWidget()
```

when keyboard is not visible the value of
`MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` is `zero`, but when keyboard pops up the value changes to somethong like `253.6`.